# Negate charactor group: match "abc'," but not "abc\',"

Tags: php, regex

I need a pattern which can negate a charactor group and also negate a charactor inside the negate group

The following pattern works, but I want to do a bit more

```
(?:(?!'\,).)+
```

Here I don't want to match strings that contain ',

But what I really need is to integrate a negation inside the negation group - something like this

```
(?:(?![^\\]'\,).)+
```

I don't want to match any escaped quote signs

Match: `abc',`

Don't match: `abc\',`

---

argh.. it posts on enter..

```
$str = "'abc\',',asdf";
preg_match("/^('(?:(?!',).)+')/", $str, $matches);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>';
```

this should output `abc\',` but it outputs `abc\`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your last comment, I think you're trying to match a single-quoted string literal, which might contain single-quotes escaped with backslashes.  For example, in this string:

```
'abc\',','xyz'
```

...you want to match `'abc\','` and `'xyz'`.  That's easy enough:

```
$source = "'abc\',','xyz'";
print "$source\n\n";
preg_match_all("/'(?:[^'\\\\]++|\\\\.)*+'/", $source, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

output:

```
'abc\',','xyz'

Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 'abc\','
        [1] => 'xyz'
    )

)
```

**[see it on ideone](http://ideone.com/uNfw7)**

But maybe you want to match all the items in a comma-separated list, which may or may not be quoted--in other words, [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) (or something very similar).  If that's the case, you should use a dedicated CSV processing tool; there are many of them out there.  In fact, PHP has one built in: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: it works! :) but whats the difference between preg_match and preg_match_all ?

Comment: `preg_match` looks for one match and stops, while `preg_match_all` keeps going until it finds all possible, non-overlapping matches.  (That is, each match attempt starts where the previous match ended.)  If you change `preg_match_all` to `preg_match`, you'll see it only returns one match: `'abc\','`

Answer (score 1):

`/^(?:(?!\\\\',).)+$/` appears to do what you want. Note that you have to escape the single quote `''`. See http://ideone.com/ypln2

If you don't necessarily want to match the full string, remove the `^` and `$`. See http://ideone.com/G67RV

Comment: <?
$str = "'abc\',',asdf";
preg_match("/^('(?:(?!',).)+')/", $str, $matches);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>';
?>

Comment: @user and what do you want the output to be?